# Is it possible to make multi-axis barcharts for AngularJS nvD3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to build a bar chart using AngularJS nvd3 with multi axis each for grade and year of a student. sofar using ndv3 library i can make upto only single axis grouped bar charts as shown in fig 1

**barchart with single x-axis display:**

[image]

But I need to add another axis for grade on top of this. Is it possible with nvd3 built in library?

**expected bar chart with grouped multi-line x-axis display**

[image]

Comment: You need to show more of your work. What have you tried?

Comment: the output of image with label "barchart with single x-axis display" is what i have implemented in using d3, but the other img with label "expected bar chart with grouped multi-line x-axis display " is  currently implemented in my project using a proprietary charting library, i am trying to replace it with nvd3...but in nvd3 documentation i didnt see any such like multi-axis grouping or adding a additional x-axis. I am trying to check if i implement it using nvd3.

Comment: Edit your answer to add the code you've got so far.